How to Exclude a Specific Agent from Running Jobs in Azure Pipelines YAML?
I'm working with Azure Pipelines and have a setup where I have multiple local agents in a pool. However, one of these agents is failing frequently, and I want to ensure that my pipeline does not run on this specific agent.
I am looking for a way to configure my pipeline to avoid running on this failing agent.

As a workaround, you may add a custom property to your needed build agents... like healthy then use demands:

Configure agent capabilities
Configure demands


pool:
  name: Default
  demands: healthy# check for healthy


To prevent your pipeline from running on the failing agent, you can disable the specific agent within your self-hosted agent pool. For this, please navigate to the Agent Pools settings in Azure DevOps, locate the agent causing issues, and toggle off the Enabled option. This will ensure that no jobs are assigned to this agent until you re-enable it.


Thanks for the info.  I don't have access to disable agent. Can we skip that agent via yaml  ?

No, I am afraid we cannot skip an agent that can be assigned for a pipeline via YAML expressions. The demands options don't support such expressions to exclude an agent. If possible, please consider running this pipeline on a certain agent with demands like Agent.Name -equals Ubuntu2204-07 until you fix the issues on the unhealthy agent.
